# How to open html page contents directly in eclipse CSH

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am using the dynamic help content in order to load default CSH for particular page in eclipse (policy in my case)
Following is the code snippet::

```java
return new IContextProvider() {

        public IContext getContext(Object target) {

            return HelpSystem
                    .getContext("com.dummy.summary");

        }

        public int getContextChangeMask() {

            return IContextProvider.SELECTION;

        }

        public String getSearchExpression(Object target) {

            return null;

        }
```

I have added the entry of CONTEXT_ID in corresponding xml file.

```xml
<context id="summary" title="Dummy POLICY">
    <topic href="html/PII/policy_summary.htm" label="Policy Summary"/>
</context>
```

Currently when I open the page and press F1 button for fetching context sensitive help
for that particular page, on right side of eclipse a help dialog appears with Title
"Dummy Policy" and link "Policy Summary" appears and on click these link (policy_summary.htm) pages opens.

What I want is to open these policy_summary.htm page directly in the dialog box appearing on right side of the window on pressing F1 key.How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can include a `description` element in the context, the contents of this are shown on the dialog.

An example from the JDT context helps:

```xml
<context id="typing_preference_page_context">
    <description>On this page you can indicate your smart typing preferences for the Java editor.

The preferences on this page are only considered if <b>Smart Insert Mode</b> appears in the status line. This can be toggled in the <b>Edit</b> menu.</description>
    <topic label="Java editor preferences" href="reference/preferences/java/ref-preferences-editor.htm"/>
    <topic label="Java editor concepts" href="concepts/concept-java-editor.htm"/>
    <topic label="Java editor reference" href="reference/views/ref-java-editor.htm"/>
</context>
```

Comment: I added <description> element in the context, but it does not solve the problem, that html page still not opening directly

Comment: You can't make the page open directly, all you can is put text in the description.